# compiling browserify for production

Tags: jquery, browserify, browserify-shim

I'm trying to compile a production `APP.JS` where `APP.JS` is processed by browserify.

`APP.JS` BEFORE COMPILE

```
require('../../components/migrate-1.2.1.min.js');
require('../../components/backjs');
require('../../components/hover.js');
```

The compiled version still shows the paths exactly as above but the content of the files are also included. How can these paths get cleaned up in production? It's revealing alot of my backend architecture and I would like to hide this.

Comment: I think that first of all you should tell us what do you expect as result? There are require calls all over your code and if you remove path specification, it would be hard to identify which module you want to actually load, especially when names would be conflicting.

Comment: I have the same question, why is it you have to bundle 100% of your app when clearly some code will not be directly invoked by the client.